# Evento onClick do Javascript não funciona com o data-modal - Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, javascript-eventos

Tenho um DataTable na minha Index no qual as linhas são carregadas usando JavaScript. Os botões Editar, Detalhes, Excluir e Histórico são criados juntamente. Todos eles abrem em uma janela modal (o bloco modal está dentro da Index)... No html de cada botão há uma tag "data-modal" no qual servirá como referência para o evento onclick que fará com que o tal botão seja aberto na janela Modal.

```js
"columns": [
            { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "descricao", "name": "Descricao", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "pessoaTipoDescricao", "name": "PessoaTipo", "autoWidth": true },
            {
              
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a btnEditar title="Editar" data-modal="" href="/situacoes-gerenciamento/editar-situacao/' + full.id + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default edit-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-edit"></span></a> |' +
                           '<a title="Detalhes" data-modal="" href="/situacoes-gerenciamento/situacao-detalhes/' + full.id + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default footable-row-detail-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-search"></span></a> |' +
                           '<a title="Excluir" asp-action="Delete" data-modal="" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default remove-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-trash"></span></a> |' +
                           '<a title="Histórico" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default clockpicker" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pessoaHistory" data-original-title="Histórico"><span class="icon-2x wb-time"></span></a>'
                }
            }
        ],
```

Problema: Ao clicar no botão "Editar" a tag "data-model" parece não estar sendo reconhecida e o evento onclick não está funcionando:

```js
 $('a[data-modal]').on('click', function (e) {
        // Abre a janela modal com o formulário solicitado 
        openmodal(this.href);
        return false;
    });
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Mas o atributo `data-modal` não tem valor. Era suposto estar sem valor ?

Comment: O data-modal fica sem valor mesmo. É que quando eu carregava o datatable sem usar o Javascript, o data-modal recebe string vazia. É que já tenho um bloco na minha Index que controi a janela modal. O atributo data-modal serve apenas para eu chamar no evento onclick...

Comment: O Interessante é que o botão Cadastrar Novo não é construído usando JS e funciona normalmente. O botão EDITAR , que foi construído via JS não funciona... Parece que o data-modal não funciona... <a id="btnNovo" asp-action="Create" data-modal="" class="btn btn-outline btn-default new" data-toggle="tooltip"
                   data-original-title="Cadastrar Novo" data-container="body">
                    <span title="Cadastrar Novo" class="icon wb-plus"></span> Cadastrar Novo
                </a>

Answer (score 0):

Está faltando um `]` no `$('a[data-modal')`

Comment: Que descuido... Postei com um erro... Mas Atualmente está com a chave fechada... Vou corrigir o post. O Problema continua...